# Find and replace in div tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have div tag with css class name. div class name is same in for other div tags. I want findout a text inside the div tag with css class name and replace with next text

```
  <div class="ms-listdescription">            
 Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library.
  </div>
```

with new text

```
 <div class="ms-listdescription">             
      Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library 
           <br/> new text.
    </div>
```

**Update:** This is very simple just find text "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library" in  if it is matches text then only append new text with existing text.

Comment: Possible: `$(".ms-listdescription").append( $("<br> new text.") );`

Comment: I need to verify with this text "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library" then only I have to append new text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that it contains text by using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
$(".ms-listdescription:contains('Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library')")
    .html(
        $(".ms-listdescription").html() + $("<br>new text")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $("div.ms-listdescription").html();
if( txt == "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library" ) {
 $("div.ms-listdescription").html( txt + "<br/>new text" );
}
```

see above -- is this what you want?

Comment: I need to verify with this text "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library" then only I have to append new text

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completly understand your question but I think you want the jquery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function

your code would look like this

```
$('.ms-listdescription').append('<br/> NEWTEXT');
```

This is better than the .[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) because it does not clear the inside it just adds to the end of the stuff in the div.

Comment: I need to verify with this text "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library" then only I have to append new text.

Comment: I am really not sure I understand now

Comment: This is simple find text in <div> if it is matches then only append new text with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ms-listdescription').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html() === "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library") {
        $(this).append('<br/>new text');
    }
});
```